# Deserializing custom array with RestSharp / JSON.NET

Tags: asp.net, json.net, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp / JSON.NET to talk to an API which returns a collection like this:

```
{
    "count": 100,
    "0":
    {
        "title":"some title"
    },
    "1":
    {
        "title":"some title"
    },
    ....
}
```

Rather than in the usual format:

```
{
    "count": 100,
    "items":
    [
        {
            "title":"some title"
        },
        {
            "title":"some title"
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

Is there a straightforward way to get RestSharp / JSON.NET to parse the first example correctly, i.e. into an Item[] array property on my deserialized object?

Will I need to write a custom deserializer?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the API? Can you change it? The way you are getting the items seems very weird to me. You're not getting a collection of objects but separate objects of the same type. I mean that your BO would look like this to map what you are getting:

```
    class YourBO
    {
        int count;
        YourProperty prop0;
        YourProperty prop1;
        ...
    }
```

Instead of getting a collection of properties as it would with your second example:

```
    class YourBO
    {
        int count;
        IEnumerable<YourProperty> props;
    }
```

So unless you have a finite and known number of items, the design of the json you are getting doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

That collection doesnt obey the usual json format, so some sort of override of json net is required. You might be able to write a json net custom converter [Custom Conveter](http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidHoerster/archive/2011/07/26/json.net-custom-convertersndasha-quick-tour.aspx), You should then be able to get that into RestSharp.

Or you could take the entire object as a JObject which would at least give you an object you could loop through and convert to a list.

Though it is essentially the same thing as a custom deserialiser you just get it into a very generic object first and go from there, better than working with a string :)